# Create a backoffice with Laravel & Hesto multi-auth

Tags: php, laravel

i'm trying to use Laravel with its Hesto for multiAuth ... 
I managed to create an admin and an user registration form and login (the easiest part).

I want to create a CRUD in the backoffice so I created a Controller and a model named :

```
php artisan make:controller CrudController --resource --model=Crud
```

it generated correctly my Model and Controller... In my Controller I return the view :

```
public function index()
{
    return view('admin.crud');
}
```

then I also created a route:

```
Route::get('/admin/crud', CrudController@index);
```

When i reach the page /admin/route it calls the index method of the CrudController ...

I would like to make this page available only if admin is logged in ...

My problems are the  following :

- I want to make this page available to admin only and to redirect non logged user to the login page
- I want to create records which include the user name(or ID or whatever ...)

You may notice that i'm not a confirmed developper and I thank you all for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is, you can add additional field to `users` table like `usertype` which will store `admin|normal_user`(whatever you want to distinguish between users).

Then, in controller you can check as below,

```
if(Auth::user()->usertype == 'admin')
    return view('admin.crud');
else
    //redirect where you want
```

> Note : Above way will not help you when your views count increases and application complexity increases. It will get cumbersome to manage `if-else`

---

Alternative way is using [Laravel Permission Package](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission).

> This package allows you to manage user permissions and roles in a database.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... I fixed one part of the issue thanks to you ... In fact i use 2 tables for users and admins...

Comment: But for authentication only one table is used i.e `users`. Which part you fixed and which is remaining?

Comment: In fact Hesto is a multi auth tool which allow you to setup different type of users .. it generates differents guards and different login... i have to manage the CRUD ... i'll try to find more information about it :))

Answer (score 0):

As I use Hesto different guards are setted up in config/auth.php...

```
'guards' => [
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],

    'user' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'admin-api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
],
```

So a solution consist on using the answer posted by Vaibhavraj Roham and to use an if statement and the concerned guard:

```
public function index()
{
    if(Auth::guard('admin')->check())
        return view('admin.sectors');
    else
        return view('admin.home');
}
```

I still have to know now how to create records which include the admin name(or ID)...

Thanks for your answer